# ul - li to 2 drop targets

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put together this project.
In my list I have fruit & veg.I want to be able to drag the right item into the correct box. Once it is in the correct box ( dropped) it should be invisible.
Hope someone can help.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <h1>THIS IS A TEST PAGE</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>


  </nav>
  <section>
    <h1>Choose a Box</h1>
    <ul id="fruit">Fruit
    </ul>
    <ul id="veg">Veg
    </ul>



  </section>

  <article>

    <ul id="dragsource">
      <li id="item1" draggable="true">Apple</li>
      <li id="item2" draggable="true">Banana</li>
      <li id="item3" draggable="true">Orange</li>
      <li id="item4" draggable="true">Potato</li>
      <li id="item5" draggable="true">Carrot</li>
      <li id="item6" draggable="true">Pea</li>
    </ul>

  </article>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
      var target1 = document.getElementById("fruit");
      var target2 = document.getElementById("veg");

      var list = document.querySelectorAll("#dragsource li");
      for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].draggable = true;
        list[i].ondragstart = function(event) {
          var event = event || window.event;
          var dt = event.dataTransfer;
          dt.setData("text", event.target.id);
          dt.effectAllowed = "move";
        };
      }


      target1.ondragover = function(event) {
        var event = event || window.event;
        event.preventDefault();
      };

      target2.ondragover = function(event) {
        var event = event || window.event;
        event.preventDefault();
      };


      target2.ondrop = function(event) {
        var event = event || window.event;
        var dt = event.dataTransfer;
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = dt.getData("text");
        target2.appendChild(document.getElementById("data"));
      };

      target1.ondrop = function(event) {
        var event = event || window.event;
        var dt = event.dataTransfer;
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = dt.getData("text");
        target1.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      };

    };
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

nav {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

body,
html {
  background-color: silver;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 482px;
  height: 220px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

#fruit {
  width: 90px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
}

#veg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 340px;
  top: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
}

article {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 170px;
  width: 482px;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  margin: left;
  column-count: 3;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #CCCCFF;
  border: 2px double #CCCCCC;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cq2aw1dy/3/

Comment: It'd be easier if you could put a fiddle together so that we can see it easier and don't have to individually do this. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Dane Questions should be answerable without a fiddle. You should encourage the OP to ask a clearer question instead of creating a fiddle that may be just as confusing. If jsfiddle were to happen to go down the question would be un-answerable, thus making it not suited to be on SO..

Comment: @Adjit Who says you can't include both?

Comment: Sorry but my understanding of all this is very small and so please take this into account. Not sure what is not clear in my question. Fruit into the box maked fruit ,veg into the veg box when they are in the correct box they are invisable

Comment: @Michael when did I say the OP could not do that? Just said questions should be answerable without a fiddle.

Comment: It does not matter, OP put up their code. it takes 5 seconds to put in a fiddle and another 5 seconds to answer the question, While you have been disusing this, I already gave the OP a good solution "with a fiddle".

Comment: @Adjit You said the question would be unanswerable without a fiddle but it wouldn't because the existing HTML, CSS and JS would still be there. You implied adding a fiddle somehow detracts from the question. Which it does not.

Comment: Dane sorry I have no experience of jsfiddle. I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

Before starting - it should be noted in your `target2.onDrop` function, the last line you say `document.getElementById("data")` there shouldn't be any quotes there. That will give you some issues.

Since all of your fruits have `ID`'s I think it would serve you better to make use of `classes` The way to do that would be to add a `class` to the dropped element that tells it to become invisible.

**CSS**

```
#fruit > .hiddenDrop, #veg > .hiddenDrop {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript** - Place this inside of your `.onDrop()` functions

```
var element = document.getElementById(data);
element.setAttribute('class', 'hiddenDrop');
target.appendChild(element);
```

What this does is after the element is dropped, it adds the class `hiddenDrop` to that element which will then change it's `display` property to `none`

Comment: Adjit thank you for your help. If you don't mind would write the class changes for me. I really don't understand this and got this far by finding bits of code and putting it together. I have tried to find example but what I did was not successful. cheers

Comment: I tried this but did not work --    <ul>
 <li class="dragsource">
 </li>
<li>Fruit
<ul>
<li class="dragsource" draggable="true">Apple</li>
<li class="fruit" draggable="true">Banana</li>
<li class="fruit" draggable="true">Orange</li>
</ul></li>
<li>Veg
<ul>
<li class="veg" draggable="true">Potato</li>
<li class="veg" draggable="true">Carrot</li>
<li class="veg" draggable="true">Pea</li>
</ul></li>
</ul>

Comment: Do I have to answer like this. not sure how these replys work Please see above comments

Comment: @aceuk007 yes, I see. Let me make an example for you

Comment: @aceuk007 so I had a mistake... you need to use `.setAttribute` instead of `ClassName`. Try it now

Comment: I now have list items dropping in both boxes and disappearing. but can you do it so only fruit goes into the fruit box and only veg into the veg box. I can't do the class bit as explained in comment above.Thanks

Comment: @aceuk007 isn't that what you are going for? if you need to run a check on the item you should really look into using 2 helper functions: 1- `isFruit(var element)` and 2- `isVegetable(var element)` and use those to function's to check if it is a fruit or a vegetable and then based upon the success/failure of those functions you can use an `if` statement to tell the program what to do next

Comment: do I not have to change my id's to class now.

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything to your `id`s

Comment: so just to confirm I now don't have to change my li's id's to class. 
This is how they look        <ul id="dragsource">
      <li id="item1" draggable="true">Apple</li>    I now have no class in my script so why do I need this -        element.setAttribute('class', 'hiddenDrop');        I really don't understand coding and got this far by finding bits of code and putting it together.
I will try and find an example of     isFruit(var element)    &     if      as stated above I have no idea how do this.
If you have time would you mind writing it for me. Cheers

Comment: You should really read up on some basic programming. I'm not sure if you'll find anything on isFruit. I just made that up, but I call it a helper function because instead of writing the same if statement over and over again you call this function that you created and have it do all of the work for you. You shouldn't change your ids because that is how your functions are currently finding the element that is being dragged

Comment: I have done a fair bit of reading but it just does not make much sense to me. I know next to nothing and to learn up to this level would take a long time. I was just trying to put together a small project. Thank you for your help

Comment: @aceuk007 sometimes when you are working up close you can miss the big picture. Break your issue down, then see what steps you need to take. Work through your program logically before jumping into code

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You can do it with the css like this `#fruit > *{display: none;}`

It is saying if you drag into the fruit div, display is set to none.

See fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cq2aw1dy/4/

Comment: adam this works , but what I wanted is for the fruit to only be allowed in the Fruit Box and the veg to only be allowed in the Veg Box. Items to disappear on drop in correct box. thanks

Comment: adam I have added    #veg > *{display: none;}    so I now get both boxes. just need to stop fruit going into veg box and vice verser

Comment: Do I have to answer like this. Please see above comments

Comment: do you have a solution to this - can you do it so only fruit items on list goes into the fruit box and only veg into the veg box.

Comment: Here I did it with the fruits https://jsfiddle.net/cq2aw1dy/7/ see the if statement in the drag event

Comment: @aceuk007 did you get that?

Comment: Sorry for late reply busy visiting over weekend. I have applied it to veg and seems to work ok. Can I ask when using jsfiddle why is script put in the html section . Also is there a way of writing    if(data === "item1" to data === "item3" ){ save writing every item ,as this is just an example and there will be 80 - 100 names on a list. One last thing would you mind if I contacted you if I was to get stuck in the future. Thank you for your help

Comment: You could build it using objects instead, it is just harder to see it as an answer if you are not familiar with using objects. Here is a intro to OOP https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: And if you look up my SO username on Facebook, you can ask me questions in a message there.